# How to create APK from kivy/python on windows?

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk, buildozer

I know it has been asked a lot of times, but I am still confused. I want to create an apk from my kivy app I created. What are the options to do this on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use a virtual machine, as described e.g. [here](http://inclem.net/2019/05/19/kivy/running_buildozer_in_a_virtual_machine/).

2) Use the "Windows subsystem for Linux" environment, which is easy to install and provided by Microsoft themselves. This isn't actively supported by the Kivy team, but apparently works.